# Ubuntu upgrade to 20.04 problematic

Tags: boot, 20.04, upgrade

I upgraded two computers from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 recently, and while one is working without issues, the second one goes offline after about half an hour of powering it up.

I connected the second computer to a monitor and a keyboard and though I could get to the `BIOS` by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>, it was not passing beyond the Dell logo screen after powering on.

However, my colleague said this is normal for servers. I also reset the problem machine to factory setting from the BIOS. But the problem still remains that the machine goes offline after about half an hour.

How should I proceed with the debug?

Comment: After I did the same upgrades on Dell R320 I had to re do the power settings they had gone back to default. Review all power settings.

Comment: So, I see the following power management options and their settings: AC Recovery (Power Off), Auto On Time (Disabled), Deep Sleep Control (Enabled in S4 and S5), USB Wake Support (Enable - not selected), Wake on LAN(Disabled), Block Sleep (not selected). For one thing, I think we have to block sleep, but I am also trying to look up and see if I can find the recommended settings for the other features.

Comment: What does "go offline" actually mean? Do you mean the server switches off or the network connection dies? And what does "half an hour" mean? Is it exactly 30 minutes?  Machines are very precise -- if it's exactly and always 30 minutes, it might be a setting somewhere... And no, I don't think your colleague is correct -- this isn't "normal" for servers.  However, installing Ubuntu on servers require a bit of patience...  If you're out of ideas and your data and work are on separate partitions, you can consider doing a fresh install of 20.04.

Comment: Going offline refers to the fact that it refuses ssh access though ping is active for some more time and then that goes away too. I think the machine goes to sleep. For now I solved this problem by masking Ubuntu power management options:
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

Comment: Also, its not exactly 30 minutes, but it seems to be the same every time. I haven't noticed the exact minutes.